# Using Express, can I automatically trim all incoming POSTed fields in req.body?

Tags: node.js, validation, express, trim

I started by using [express-form](https://github.com/freewil/express-form) with my api (Express 3.3.8) in order to trim leading and trailing whitespace off of incoming POSTed fields.

However, I believe to use it I must include the form fields and rules in my middleware to my routes like so:

`app.post('/api/test', form(
    field("username").trim(),
    field("password").trim(), function(req, res...`

My question is, is there a way to do the trim automatically without specifying the fields individually? I know of the configuration option: `autoTrim`, but I think I still need to specify the fields on a per route/middleware basis, right? I tried leaving it out of the middleware, and just doing the `form.configure({autoTrim:true})`, but nothing changed with the `req.body` fields. Same as if I never included `express-form` at all.

I'm not committed to `express-form`. If there's another way already available to have Express always trim incoming `req.body` fields, please let me know.

Comment: Look at the config toward the very bottom of the readme. *"autoTrim (Boolean): If true, all fields will be automatically trimmed. Default: false."*

Comment: @KevinB,  I saw, I noted that in my post. I believe I still need to specify the fields individually though. Even with that option.

Comment: Did you try? would probably be much more time efficient to try than to ask.. If you already have, you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: But, to directly answer your question, Yes, with express middleware, you can automagically trim all incoming posted fields in request.body. There may or may not be an already written middleware for that purpose. If there isn't you could write one yourself.

Comment: @KevinB, Yes, tried that. I'll be clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it seems one must declare the fields individually using `express-form`, I decided to write my own whitespace trimming middleware for now as I couldn't find an existing simple solution. I use `underscore.js`, so you'll see its `map` function in use. You could otherwise do your own looping with the native `Object.keys` or similar. This completely rewrites all fields in `req.body`! Please note, this is a stop-gap for a greater validation issue. We're just doing this temporarily until we have time to clean up validation as a whole. Here's my code (put before `app.use(app.router)` of course):

```
var trimmer = function(req, res, next){
  req.body = _.object(_.map(req.body, function (value, key) {
    return [key, value.trim()];
  }));
  next();
}

app.use(trimmer);
```

Comment: My 2 cents here - if the value is an array, you want to check Array.isArray(value)  and return [key, value.map(v => v.trim())];

Comment: better to use lodash over underscore which is superset of underscore

Answer (score 11):

```
app.use(postTrimmer);

function postTrimmer(req, res, next) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(req.body)) {
            if (typeof(value) === 'string')
                req.body[key] = value.trim();
        }
    }
    next();
}
```

Don't forget to turn on the `"body-parser"` module before using `postTrimmer` middleware.

Comment: It worked for me, but, as a suggestion, I would add a check if the typeof value is a string:  if(typeof(value)==="string")
                req.body[key] = value.trim();

Comment: it will not working if we have sub objects in the body e.g `{ param1: "    it will be trimmed     
 ", param2: { subparam: "        it will NOT be trimmed "             } }`

Comment: @John you can edit the answer if you'd like. I haven't been using JS since then and can make a mistake.

Comment: why do you check for string ? is not app web sent as string?

Answer (score 3):

I created a npm module for the very purpose. It provides you 4 middlewares that you can use to trim req.body, req.query, req.params or all three. It also provides a separate utility which you can use to trim any object.
This module works recursively so doesn't matter how nested the string is in object, It will be trimmed.

[request_trimmer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request_trimmer)

```
npm i request_trimmer
```

---

```
const express =  require('express');
const app = express();
    
const { trim_all,trim_body,trim_params,trim_util } = require('request_trimmer');
app.use(express.json());
#trim request body and query.
app.use(trim_all)
```