# Loopback: Apply trim function to all incoming string properties

Tags: node.js, loopback

I would like to trim all the strings that are sent in an HTTP request to my loopback project. There are validators that I can use in the model files, but is there something I can do before the request reaches the model?

Thank You

Comment: Which framework you are using for the project? Also, what is the type(GET, POST, etc..) of the HTTP request?

Comment: I am using Loopback 2.0. The type of request is POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom express middleware to trim your request data fields.

```
var trimmer = function(req, res, next){
  req.body = _.object(_.map(req.body, function (value, key) {
    return [key, value.trim()];
  }));
  next();
}

app.use(trimmer);
```

[Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30267397/3087801) for better understanding.

Comment: Include it in the file where you are registering the middlewares like bodyParser.json().