# ExpressJs Trim middleware for nested req.body data

Tags: node.js, express

How could I create a middleware to trim all *req.body* data even **NESTED** data?

I also accept a trusted well coded package.

Noting that I am using **true** here :
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

this code ref [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266295/using-express-can-i-automatically-trim-all-incoming-posted-fields-in-req-body)

```
  trim: (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(req.body)) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') req.body[key] = value.trim();
      }
    }
    next();
  }
```

This one will work but not for nested data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this in a single line is to utilise the recursion built into JSON.stringify's `replacer` functionality, check value is number or string then trim it, then parse the result back into an object.

```js
let obj = {
  "a": "f",
  "b": {
    "c": " g",
    "d": "h",
    "x": {
      "a": [
       '1 ', '2 ', '3 '
      ]
    }
  },
  "e": " value3 "
};

obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => ['string', 'number'].includes(typeof v) ? v.trim() : v))

console.log(obj)
```

Or you could use a recursive function, which if value is object, array then recall the function, lots of example around on that, do a search.

Comment: This does work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through each object and array recursively and trim accordingly

```
function trim(body) {
  for (const key in body) {
    if (typeof body[key] === "object" || Array.isArray(body[key])) {
      trim(body[key]);
    } else if (typeof body[key] === 'string') {
      body[key] = body[key].trim();
    }
  }
};

handleReq: (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    trim(req.body);
  }
  next();
}
```

Comment: This does not work properly